# simpler way of grouping numerous variables by value of select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, grouping, simplify

thanks for looking.

im still learning the more complex javascript and jquery coding so could do with some help as i have no idea about the following or even if its possible!

i need a better/simpler/shorter way of doing the following (please note i have removed the irrelevant validation etc coding): 
'

```
function Findbox5( myform, box1, box2, box3, box4, box5, Storeall, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5)
   {
   //store values
     Myform = document.forms.myform;
     box1 = Myform.box1.value;
     box2 = Myform.box2.value;
     box3 = Myform.box3.value;
     box4 = Myform.box4.value;
     box5 = Myform.box5.value;
     s1 = Myform.s1.value;
     s2 = Myform.s2.value;
     s3 = Myform.s3.value;
     s4 = Myform.s4.value;
     s5 = Myform.s5.value;

     //set as one string

     Storeall = s1 + ":" + box1 + ";" + s2 + ":" + box2 + ";" + s3 + ":" + box3 + ";" + s4 + ":" + box4 + ";" + s4 + ":" + box5 + ";" ;

     // next function...

   } '
```

as you can see i have 5 input boxes and relevant selects for each box(each select has 4 options:1,2,3,4.). when a user enters data into a box they choose a relevant option. all boxes and options must be entered then they submit the form.

this data will be emailed to me as the variable stored under storeall. which would be something like 1:1234;2:1324;1:3232;4:5434;2:3211;

so what i hope to do is simplify this data into the following with either a seperate function or the same one: 1:1234-3232;2:1324-3211;4:5434;

is this possible? or have i done it the easiest way?

any comments or help welcomed, thanks again

Comment: Why does the function accept parameters if it's not going to do anything with their values but overwrite them?

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll want to group these things into a single element that can be iterated against. So if your HTML looks like:

```
<form>
    <input name="s1" />
    <input name="box1" />
    <input name="s2" />
    <input name="box2" />
    ...
</form>
```

Then it's probably better to do something like:

```
<form>
    <div class="set">
        <input class="s" name="s1" />
        <input class="box" name="box1" />
    </div>
    <div class="set">
        <input class="s" name="s2" />
        <input class="box" name="box2" />
    </div>
    ...
</form>
```

Now you've established some commonality among these elements, instead of just different names/IDs. Each set of inputs is grouped by the `.set` class, and within each set, you know there's going to be two inputs: one with the `.s` class, and one with the `.box` class. Now iterating against them with JQuery is easy:

```
var str = "";
$("form div.set").each(
    function(index, element)
    {
        currentValueS = $(element).find("input.s").val();
        currentValueBox = $(element).find("input.box").val();
        str += currentValueS + ":" + currentValueBox + ";";
    }
);
```

This uses JQuery's `.each()` function. `.each()` allows you to provide a function to perform on each of the elements that JQuery finds from the indicated selector. Here, your selector is `form div.set`, which means "all `div` elements that have the class of `.set`, and are found anywhere under any `form` element". For each of these elements, you'll need to find the value of the `<input>` element with the `.s` class, and also the value of the `<input>` element with the `.box` class. Then you just add those to your growing `str` variable.

Comment: thanks for the help and detailed explanation, this is a lot simpler way of setting the emailed string, but am i right in thinking this will not store each box data to the relevant "heading" ie all s1's are put first then s2's etc.
edit: just had a thought i could store box values to one of 4 variables (s1, s2 etc) by using an if or switch statement... does this sound ok?

Answer (score 0):

If you want everything in the form, you should use [`serializeArray`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) :

```
$('#my_form').submit(function() {
  var str = '';
  $.each($(this).serializeArray(), function () {
      str += this.name + ":" + this.value + ";";
  });
  sendByMail(str);
  return false;
});
```